# sqlite deletion query not working in react-native

Tags: react-native, sqlite

I am new to mobile development and I would like to perform simple queries like deleting a row a specific from my sqlite table. But It doesnt work.The row still exits in my database table
This is my code:

```
 export default class App extends Component{
  constructor(props){
      super(props);
      db = SQlite.openDatabase(
      {
        name: 'gad.db',
        createFromLocation: 1,
      },
      this.successToOpenDB,
      this.failToOpenDB,  
      );
    }
    successToOpenDB()
    {
      db.transaction(tx => 
      {
          tx.executeSql("DELETE FROM songs WHERE content='content2' ", [] ,(tx, results) => 
          {
            console.log('DELETION OK');
          },
            (tx, error) => 
          {
              console.log("DELETION KO");
          });
       
       });
    }
    failToOpenDB(err){
      console.log(err);
      alert("not connected to database");
    }
```

Please anyone help.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Must be some issue with primary key, if primary key is your condition to delete,
or "content" here.

First try to retrieve primary key of the row you want to delete, and store in
some state maybe:

```js
     var deleted= results.rows.item(length-1).ID
```

I have primary key as ID, so I am now able to get required row.

also, after delete query you can check any rows affected or not in promise returned as follows:

```js
  (tx, results) => {
       if( results.rowsAffected >0) {
           //then proceed ahead.
         }
    }
```